# Set center and zoom after CQL filter

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2

I need to display map on the submenu `li` click with CQL filter which works for me but map displayed is as shown in screenshot. I am unable to adjust its center and zoom.

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
var state="<%=state%>";
var wms;
$("#submenu li").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('value');
var cql_filter="st_nm='"+state+ "'";
    wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
        "http://localhost:8083/geoserver/wms", {layers: [id], 'CQL_Filter': cql_filter}    );
    map.addLayer(wms);
    map.zoomToMaxExtent();
    document.getElementById("firstmap").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("map").style.visibility = 'visible';});
```

[image]

Comment: Setting a filter on a layer won't change the maxExtent of the map.  If the filter uses a bbox you could parse the filter string to create an extent array from that.

Comment: or make a WFS request with a filter to get the bounds